# Binding the output from an Ember helper to the value of an Ember input helper

Tags: ember.js

I wrote a Ember/Handlebars helper to format a date using Moment.js:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('formattedDate', function(date, format) {
    var formattedDate = moment(date).format(format);
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(formattedDate);
});
```

Now, I want to use that in tandem with an Ember input helper like so (where startDate is a property on the model in scope):

```
{{input id="startDatePicker" class="form-control" value={{formattedDate startDate 'MMM D'}} required=true}}
```

But that doesn't work and throws a syntax error. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid a syntax error by using a subexpression (see more about subexpressions [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/#toc_link-to-helper)).

So, you would do:

`{{input id="startDatePicker" class="form-control" value=(formattedDate startDate 'MMM D')}}`

at which point you won't get a syntax error, but it still will behave weird. What I suggest you do instead is implement a computed property for formatted date instead. See the following answer I recently gave, which should give you a good starting point

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28774170/908842

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems like subexpressions don't actually work for boundHelpers though, only normal helpers. But I used your second suggestion and just created a computer property in the controller. My helper was supposed to help me avoid the need for this computed property in a number of different controllers, but oh well.